# Need help repeating If statement after else statement execute

Tags: java

Need help repeating If statement after else statement execute
if(y > 1650 ) {
        Premus.delay(100);

```
    Premus.mouseMove(120, 990);

    Premus.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    Premus.delay(100);

    Premus.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    //Starts Video
     y = 0;  
    }   
else { 
        do{
            Premus.mouseMove(1650, 850);

            Premus.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            Premus.delay(10);

            Premus.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            y++;
     }while (y < 16500);}
```

want to repeat if statement after else statement is done, y= 0 at start of code

Comment: Can you please please share the whole if-else block?

Comment: Try putting a loop around things you want to happen repeatedly.

Comment: Anyway, you can put a while loop outside the if-else block, iterating until a certain condition is true and you can set this condition to false in the then branch of the if block.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to repeat a line or block of code multiple times, you use a loop (for-loop prefered).

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
    //Your code here
}
```

At the end of the loop, the "i<10" expression will be evaluated. Modify it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into a function, then start calling this function in else  when y == 16500

Thanks